# Product Images Not Uploading

Tags: php-5.4, product-images

Making use of the [addImageToMediaGallery](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product.html#addImageToMediaGallery) method against a Product, I am attempting to upload an image from our application to Magento.

The image is successfully being created on the server but the image is not being linked to the product using the PHP:

```
<?php

include_once '../../app/Mage.php';

try {

  Mage::app();

  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_POST["product_id"]);
  $product->setStoreId($_POST["store_id"]);
  $bytes = base64_decode($_POST["image_bytes"]);

  $importDir = "Upload/" . $_POST["label"];
  $output = fopen($importDir, wb);
  fwrite($output, $bytes);
  fclose($output);

  if (file_exists($importDir) ) {

    $media = array();

    if ($_POST["is_thumbnail"] == "1") {
      array_push($media, 'thumbnail');
    }

    if ($_POST["is_small"] == "1") {
      array_push($media, 'small_image');
    }

    if ($_POST["is_base"] == "1") {
      array_push($media, 'image');
    }

    foreach ($media as $imageType) {
      if (file_exists($importDir)) {
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($importDir, $imageType, false);
      }
    }

  } else {
    echo "Uploaded image not found at $importDir";
  }

  echo "true";

} catch(Exception $e) {
  Mage::logException($e);
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Any help would be appriecated

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a save call once the addImageToMediaGallery method had been called after the foreach loop iteration had completed.

Simply added in the following:

```
foreach ($media as $imageType) {
  if (file_exists($importDir)) {
    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($importDir, $imageType, false);
  }
}

**$product->save();**
```